# Hibernate mapping - multiple tables query

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm working on an application that uses hibernate and drools files to make CRUD operations on database tables and at this point I need to provide the menu given a certain ID, which for now can be hardcoded.

I have the necessary query to make it available and I wanted to use it or emulate it in hibernate in order to call .hbm and output the result of this query.
Taking into account that I have no access to .java files and therefore I can only create .hbm and .xml files that I need to output.

I can list all the tables needed on my application to perform this query. The question that arises is: How to use all these models (hibernate mapping files that make each of these tables available) to create a single .hbm file that calls them and where can I emulate the query I need?

The query is as follows:

```
select distinct d.* from Group MB, Access AI, Item I, Module M, MenuItem D
where
mb.IdGroup = AI.IdGroup and ai.CodItem = i.CodItem and i.Module = m.Module and 
mb.CodSis = ai.CodSis and ai.CodSis = i.CodSis and i.CodSis = m.CodSis and
m.CodSis = 103 and mb.IdUtil= 29 
and
d.Coditem = i.CodItem
and
d.parentMenuID = 0
```

The hbm models to list each table are look alike this: (example to list menu table)

**Menu.hbm.xml**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="authorization.model.Menu" table="MenuItem" where="ParentMenuID = 0 ">  
      <composite-id>
      <key-property column="Id" name="id" type="int"/>
      </composite-id>
      <property column="label" name="__label" type="string"/>
    <property column="actionURL" name="__actionURL" type="string"/>
    <property column="ParentMenuID" name="__ParentMenuID" type="string"/>
    <property column="MenuID" name="__MenuID" type="int"/>
    <property column="Coditem" name="__Coditem" type="int"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<concept name="menu">
  <action name="readlist" jsonMetainfo="{
          'columns':[
              {'key':'__ParentMenuID', 'order':1, 'allowSort':false, 'type':'text', 'exportable':true},
              {'key':'__Coditem', 'order':2, 'allowSort':false, 'type':'text', 'exportable':true},
              {'key':'__label', 'order':3, 'allowSort':false, 'type':'text', 'exportable':true},
          ],
          'defaultSort':{'column':2, 'type':'asc'},
          'actions':[]
      }" />
</concept>
```

With that, i can list the menu table without any filter, just the table.
I need to emulate the query above, i've tryed to use `<many-to-one name="Item" class="authorization.model.Item" insert="false" update="false" not-found="ignore"/><many-to-one>` for all models (which list tables) that i need just to list them and make sure that i have all the tables i need in one .hbm file (listing them to make sure..) but it's not working.. 
Is there a way to execute that query given my situation?

After much search i still can't find a solution for my problem, hope somebody helps me please.